# Ajax calls do not work in IE unless you fiddle with security settings

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, activex

IE sucks, at times. Until IE 10, IE did not provide support for the XMLHttpRequest Object. Rather, you must use the XActiveXObject Object for running AJAX calls. JQuery boots up this object by default and maintains it throughout a ternary function if it is present (which is all the time, essentially, should your browser be IE).

But, you can see the problem already. In order to use this ActiveX Object, you must fiddle with the security settings in IE in order to allow scriplets, unsigned ActiveX schtuff, and the like.

Is there any way to bypass these security settings (like installing a CAB file to sign the bloody thing) so that end users do not have to fiddle with their browser settings and everything will work out of the box?

Comment: You are incorrect. The XMLHttpRequest is available in all versions of IE from IE7 onward. You only need the ActiveX object if you need to support IE6 (please tell me you don't need to support IE6 any more... please?). And jQuery will use XMLHttpRequest in preference to the ActiveX control in all those IE versions.

Comment: Are you having an issue with the ActiveX ajax instantiation? If so what progid/object name are you using? - The correct one is marked as safe-for-scripting and should work out of the box, or are you asking how to silently run arbitrary code in another ActiveX container?

Comment: Interesting.  JQuery 1.8.2 boots up the ActiveXObject first, and, if not present, uses the XMLHttpRequest object instead.  Thus, I could change JQuery itself.  But, rumors are flying that IE has not fully implemented XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: And no, we are not supporting IE6 and really, we aren't even supporting IE7.

Comment: Rumors are flying? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Support_in_Internet_Explorer_versions_5.2C_5.5.2C_and_6

Comment: Yes.  There are ample googles out there that say, due to IE's lack of full implementation, you must use the XDomainRequest Object, which has a whole host of its own restrictions.  JQuery 1.8.2 abstracts the object load process and uses the ActiveXObject instead.

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy The `XDomainRequest` option serves as a pseudo-replacement for CORS in IE8 and 9. `XMLHttpRequest` is supported enough that you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Well, the answer can be found in the [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) (line 8454). It seems that IE7 has a bug with loading *local* files using XMLHttpRequest, so *if your request is local*, then jQuery will try to use the activeX control in preference, with a fallback to XMLHttpRequest. But if it's a regular request then it will use the standard XMLHttpRequest object in preference, with a fallback to ActiveX.

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy You're misunderstanding the source.

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy I am not sure what you're asking for. In the latest versions of jQuery it only uses ActiveX in a small number of specific situations. Are you in one of those situations? Can you describe it?

Comment: @DaveMethvin Yes.  Using an Ajax call with IE, accessing a local domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here is what I did to rectify the situation.  My original question was the following:

How do I make an Ajax call in IE and force it to bypass the ActiveX Security settings.

As we discussed in the above comments, in JQuery 1.8.2, the ActiveXObject is used for IE ONLY if the ajaxsettings.isLocal is true, which, in this case, it was.  We don't support anything below IE8 which has a full implementation of XMLHttpRequest (which doesn't use ActiveX, of course) and thus I wanted to make sure that Ajax ALWAYS used XMLHttpRequest.

So, I made the following settings change at a global level:

```
$ajaxSetup({
    isLocal: false
});
```

This caused IE to always consider the Ajax call to be cross domain, forcing JQuery to use the XMLHttpRequest Object, completely bypassing the need to recognize or even care about IE's ActiveX Security settings.

Case closed.

Comment: Do you need Chrome support as well? I don't think Chrome allows local file access via XHR at all by default.

Comment: In this case, I'm not sure it matters at all.  XMLHttpRequest works just fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery doesn't favor ActiveX over XMLHttpRequest in Internet Explorer like you suggest. Rather, it checks for its presence, and then proceeds to check if the file a is a local file. If either of these conditions aren't met, then a standard XHR request is made.

```javascript
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = window.ActiveXObject 
    // If ActiveXObject exists, and the file is not local, return Standard XHR
    // If ActiveXObject exists, and the file is local, return ActiveXHR
    ? function() {
        return !this.isLocal && createStandardXHR() || createActiveXHR(); } 
    // If ActiveXObject doesn't exist, use StandardXHR
    : createStandardXHR;
```

This same thing could almost be written like this:

```javascript
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = (window.ActiveXObject && this.isLocal) 
    ? createActiveXHR() 
    : createStandardXHR();
```

Hopefully that is easier to understand.

I should note that this has changed dramatically in jQuery 2.0:

```javascript
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch( e ) {}
};
```

Comment: Curious: What is the meaning of isLocal?  What is this referring to?

Comment: It tests the protocol of the request against `/^(?:about|app|app-storage|.+-extension|file|res|widget):$/` to see if it's a request not to the web.

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy - search the code for it; it's a boolean value; the result of a regex on the location path, to determine whether the file is "local" or not (ie false if it's a web-based request; true if it's on the user's local machine).

Comment: Yep.  I found it.  Thanks!

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy There is a great deal of confusion on your part regarding Internet Explorer, and jQuery. Please be more patient next time, and not assume that "IE sucks".

Comment: This wasn't actually an answer to my question which was, "How can I bypass the ActiveX security settings?".  Any objections to overriding Ajaxsettings.isLocal and setting that to false?

Comment: Wow.  JQuery 2.0 is what needs to happen.  Nice.