# Internet Explorer Ajax not firing POST and PATCH

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm having issues with debugging sending the data to Rails controller through Ajax. Firefox and Chrome work fine, Internet Explorer fails and I assume it's got to do with something in the security settings (as on medium security it works fine, strict security just goes kaboom).

My script is simple (url comes from var elsewhere, pointing to the same domain):

```
  $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url :  url,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data : JSON.stringify({
        "survey": {
        "id": $('#survey-id').val(),
        "survey_answers_attributes": responses(),
        "user_qualities_attributes": serializeQualities()
      }
      })
    });
```

Is there any way to go about the IE security settings? I cannot reliably expect the users not to have strict security policy, especially since quite a few of them come from gov orgs with restricted networks settings.

Comment: Is there an error message in the browser's console? What version(s) of IE?

Comment: It gives me "No transport" error and if I define jQuery.support.cors = true it is unable to get property 'open' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: And you are going to the same exact domain and not a sub domain? Ports also match?

Comment: Forgot to add, it's IE10. It's the very same domain, ports do match too.

Comment: Trying to see what setting prevents ajax from firing, it looks like "Script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting" is (one of) the culprit(s). With this disabled, ajax doesn't work, when I enable it, works like a charm. Any idea how to go around that?

Comment: Is your IE10 running in IE8 mode?

Comment: It's not, same problem on IE11

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173464/ajax-calls-do-not-work-in-ie-unless-you-fiddle-with-security-settings

Comment: Tried isLocal: false, but no dice unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been finally solved by upgrading to jQuery 2. Seems like it's not bothered about trying to use IE ActiveX and thus simply works